# AWS RDS MySQL migration from default VPC to custom VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have an AWS RDS MySQL in one of the Public Subnets of one of the default VPCs.
What would be the best and smooth procedure to migrate it to an RDS MySQL located in a new custom VPC in a private subnet?
Would it be possible to create a VPC peering between both VPCs and then create an RDS Standby?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just modify it?  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-vpc-rds-db-instance/

Comment: Thanks Michael. That is a cool option too but I would say it is a little bit safer the snapshot/restore method, just in case you need a rollback for any reason

Comment: Just be sure you stop all write traffic from your application before making the snapshot, since any changes made after the snapshot process starts will not make it onto the new instance.

Comment: sure thing. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a Snapshot
2. Restore the database, select the custom VPC in the settings.
3. Update the new endpoint in your applications.

(or)

You can modify the DB settings and apply it in the next maintenance window

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-vpc-rds-db-instance/

Answer (score 0):

This is easier: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-vpc-rds-db-instance/

You can go to Databases console and modify the instance's VPC in the Network & Connectivity section.